# Is there a "target=_blank" alternative in css?

Tags: html, css

> Is there a `target=_blank` alternative in CSS?

i want `target="_blank"` using CSS.. if it possible please help me....

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: css is for style (*style*sheet). This is behavioral.

Comment: Please stop littering your questions with formatting characters. They have special meanings. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: There once was a CSS3 module spec for this. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-hyperlinks/. But it has been abandoned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a css property, so you won't find a css equivalent.
It's a behavioral attribute, similar to click

You can target these elements and select them using java script though and apply whatever style you need.

Comment: pure css, no. browser function, yes. <head> <base target="_blank" /> </head> that is the closest you will get beyond inline target="_blank"